# Promises fail for httprequest in nodejs (Parse.com)

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, promise, httprequest

I'm trying to implement 3 httprequests in series in Nodejs on a parse.com server. I'm still trying to figure out how it works. For the moment, the following codes throws no syntax error but also has a return of a single blank console.log in the server logs.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('paypalCheck', function (request, response) {
    
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ 
        method: 'POST',
        url:url1,
        body:body1
    }).then(function(httpResponse){
        console.log(httpResponse.text.split("\n")[0])
        
        var promises = [];
        var updated = false;
        if(httpResponse.text.split("\n")[0] == 'FAIL'){
            var orderUpdate = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                method: 'POST',
                            url:url2,
                headers:header2,
                body:body2
            }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                console.log('updated')
                updated = true;
                return 'order updated';
            });
            promises.push(orderUpdate);
        }
        
        if(updated){
            var orderFetch = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                method: 'GET',
                            url:url3,
                headers:header3
            }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                return_url = httpResponse.data.order.order_status_url
                return httpResponse;
            });
            promises.push(orderFetch);
        }
        
        return Parse.Promise.when(promises)
    }).then(function(httpResponse){
        console.log('result');
        console.log(httpResponse);
        response.success(return_url)
    }, function(error){
        console.log('result');
        response.error(error)
    })
})
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't even get `result` printed out? A single blank `console.log` sounds weird. And in parallell? Your code is executing the requests in sequence since you are waiting for the first `httpRequest` with `url1`. Do you want to run the requests indepedently for each url, or are they in some way dependant on each other?

Comment: Your `updated` statement looks strange, since you are setting it in a callback but you use it in the if condition (which would suggest you want to wait for the update). If that's so, I would rather go for another `then` statement on top of the `orderUpdate` request

Comment: @DanielB.. my mistake.. they should be in series.. I'm editing the question.. and yes.. it's a blank `console.log` and not even `result` is printed

Comment: @Icepickle.. my mistake, the calls are to be in series.. one after the other..

Comment: @Icepickle `2nd httprequest` should happen only when the response from `1st httprequest` matches a condition.. similarly, `3rd httprequest` should run on success on `2nd httprequest`.. the response of `3rd httprequest` is to be returned back to the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some modifications needed for your code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('paypalCheck', function (request, response) {

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ 
        method: 'POST',
        url:url1,
        body:body1
    }).then(function(httpResponse){
        console.log(httpResponse.text.split("\n")[0])

        var promises = [];
        var updated = false;
        if(httpResponse.text.split("\n")[0] == 'FAIL'){
            return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                method: 'POST',
                url:url2,
                headers:header2,
                body:body2
            }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                console.log('updated')
                updated = true;
                return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url:url3,
                    headers:header3
                });
            }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                return_url = httpResponse.data.order.order_status_url
                return httpResponse;
            });;
        }
        else console.log("FAIL was true, do nothing");
    }).then(function(httpResponse){
        console.log('result');
        console.log(httpResponse);
        response.success(return_url)
    }, function(error){
        console.log('result');
        response.error(error)
    })
})
```

First off, I've added an else condition to your check on httpResponse.text.split, just so see if it hits.

Second, I've gotten rid of your Parse.Promise.when() call and instead chained the requests you were making so they properly happen in sequence. The way you had it, the if(updated) would never pass, since the check would happen before the second httpRequest ever came back.

Let me know if this changes your output at all.

Comment: It works.. I see the folly in my code.. instead of `else console.log("FAIL was true, do nothing");` , if I want to return an error what should be done? I tried `else response.error("PayPal failed, do nothing");` but it first goes into `then(function(httpResponse){
        console.log('result');
        console.log(httpResponse);
        response.success(return_url)
    }, ` part and then returns the error.

Comment: You can either return a rejected promise (`return Parse.Promise.error("Error message");`), or return a Parse.Error (`return Parse.Error(code, message);` where code is the three digit http code of your choice.

Comment: Note: You can only call response.error/success once. And your code will keep executing anyway, and will error on the second call. With promises, not returning anything returns a resolved empty promise. Returning anything other than a rejected promise or a Parse.Error will return a resolved promise with the value. Return a rejected promise or a Parse.Error will be returned as a rejected promise. Promise chains will always continue to execute, even if you've called response.success/error. A `.then()` that has no error handler will be skipped for a rejected promise, with the error passed down the

Comment: chain until it finds an error handler.  You have to be careful here. When I was starting, I had a .then() with a success and error handler, called response.error() in the error handler, but even that will then return a resolved promise if you don't specifically return an error / rejected promise from the error handler. They can be tricky, but they're mighty powerful once you figure them out.

Answer (score 0):

I felt the problem is, you don't have declared the `return_url` var.

In this line `return_url = httpResponse.data.order.order_status_url` is used but i did't see the declaration.

When you don't have declared the vars the App crash and you won't get error, only stop works.

Also try to implement the catch clause in your Promises that probably would help you to debug.